# Weak-* convergence in $C^1([-1,1])^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, integral-operators

Given the sequence of functionals $$f_n(x)=\int_{\frac{1}{n}\leq|t|\leq1}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt$$ in $C([-1,1])$ respectively $C^1([-1,1])$.

> How can I show that $(f_n)$ weak-*-converges in $C^1([-1,1])^*$?
>
> And answer the question if it does in $C([-1,1])^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Intuitively, the weak-star limit should be the functional
$$
u \mapsto \int_{[-1,1]} t^{-1} u(t) dt.
$$
Then show that 
$$
\int_{-1/n}^{1/n} t^{-1} u(t) dt
$$ 
tends to zero for fixed $u$ by partial integration.

2) Show that these functionals are unbounded in $C([-1,1])^*$: For each $n$, take a piecewise linear function, which is equal to one on $[1/n,1]$ and zero on $[-1,0]$.